# Pytorch How to normalize new records with regard to previous dataset?

Tags: scikit-learn, normalization

I am trying to build a neural network using pytorch. I am using [`sklearn.MinMaxScaler`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html) to normalize my dataset. But how do I normalize a new incoming record that I will need to predict with regards to the mix max values of my dataset?

```py
scaler = MinMaxScaler()

scaler.fit_transform(file_x[list_of_features_to_normalize])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to use [`sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html) you need first to `fit` the scaler to the values of your *training* data. This is done (as you already did) using

```py
scaler.fit_transform(file_x[list_of_features_to_normalize])
```

After this `fit` your scaling object `scaler` has its internal parameters (e.g., `min_`, `scale_` etc.) tuned according to the training data.

Once training is done, and you wish to evaluate your model on new records you only need to apply the `scaler` *without* fitting it to the new data:

```py
val_t = scaler.transform(validation_data)
```